# Two way lookup using index and matching

Tags: excel, indexing, matching

Im still learning using excel index and matching. But when i try to do it. It didn't give the expected result. I want to take the quantity if the item and warehouse are matched

here's the link https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hvZX.jpg

Can you guys help me? I'm Lost

Comment: why not use PivotTable?

Comment: yeah, pivot much easier. But i want to learn without using pivot. Any idea? @Lambda

Comment: check my answer, @Apis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your data didn't show row numbers or column numbers, I'll give an example to deal with problems like this:

[image]

details:

1、($A$2:$A$8=$E2)*($B$2:$B$8=F$1) will return an array that meet the conditions $A$2:$A$8=$E2 `and` $B$2:$B$8=F$1. Here is {1;0;0;0;0;0;0}    ({1;0;0;0;0;0;0} * {1;0;0;0;0;0;0}).

2、0/($A$2:$A$8=$E2)*($B$2:$B$8=F$1) will return an array {0;#DIV/0!;#DIV/0!;#DIV/0!;#DIV/0!;#DIV/0!;#DIV/0!}.

3、lookup(1,{0;#DIV/0!;#DIV/0!;#DIV/0!;#DIV/0!;#DIV/0!;#DIV/0!},$C$2:$C$8) will find the first largest value of the array {0;#DIV/0!;#DIV/0!;#DIV/0!;#DIV/0!;#DIV/0!;#DIV/0!} that less than 1 and give its position, and then lookup the value at that position of $C$2:$C$8.

Hope I explain clearly.

Comment: Thank you. I need some time to fully understand your answer. This is my first time dealing with this kind formula. Thnxx